How to define a high performing typescript type mapping for a giant, literal interface?
Suppose I have a very large type mapping:
interface MegaMap {
  key1: typeof import('./key1.json'; 
  ... 
  key100000: typeof import('./key100000.json')
}

My motivating use case has 3k-4k entries. Presume that the use case is valid, and that "just don't do that" is not a valid option/response.
What strategies can I apply to make that typing experience more performant--from the compiler's perspective or the editor's perspective--if any?

This seems extremely niche. The most productive avenue is probably to dig into the TypeScript compiler's source code and look for opportunities to cache and use different data structures. If you find success, you could share the changes back with a pull request

That said, there just isn't really a fast way to read 10,000 files. I assume this file is auto-generated, in which case you might get disk IO savings by baking the type from each json file into one giant file

ahaha its a tricky question, so not sure, but I think it you set up to test stuff out, you could have a look at lazy evaluation of type, for example I think that when you express a type as a conditional like type T<K extends keyof MegaMap> = K extends string? T[K] : never might get better perfomance. Other than that idk, maybe since it just evaluates once then type results should be cached in doesnt matter, but would have to test out to know better
